# How to execute a javascript before dom is ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

I need to execute a javascript before the page is start to load? how can i do it? Atfirst my script should execute, after completion of script, if i need i should load the page else i shouln't load it. For example if my script redirect to another page i shouldnot load the current page else i should load it.

Comment: From your comments below, I'm guessing that the script is executing first, but the rest of the page has a second to load while the new HTTP request is waiting for a response. Perhaps you could try wrapping the content of the page in `<noscript>` tags.

Comment: This is a bad idea if it is for security. All of the content is sent down to the computer and anyone watching the traffic or with JS disabled can get the content.

Comment: @epascarello - Yeah, we don't know what the ultimate intention is. I was thinking it was perhaps a simple redirect to a javascript enhanced page. You're right that it is not a solution if security is in mind. But then any javascript solution would fail simply by disabling javascript.

Answer (score 6):

Do it server side ...

The logic you present, seems to fit better at the server side, if you really want to avoid the loading of the page completely..

Comment: Not sure, but I'd guess this is to redirect to a javascript enabled version of the page/site. As such, it would be browser dependent.

Comment: @patrick, looks that way .. My focus was mainly on the **load** part, which is unavoidable... for the *render* there are workarounds, indeed..

Answer (score 3):

simply write your script in the script tag as a first element in body tag:

-- updated --

for hiding other page elements, use div with full width and height, if you want to show the page, hide the div, that will fix the problem

Comment: for hiding page, use div with full width and height, if you want to show the page, hide the div, that will fix the problem

Answer (score 1):

You can't run a script before the page loads (without messing up the document type), but you can put the script early in the page, i.e. in the `head` section.

You can't stop the page from loading until your script has finished. The page will continue to load in the background, but it will not render until the script has finished.

If you do a redirect in your script, the page will stop loading, but what's already loaded will render while waiting for the new response to arrive.

Comment: Your answer was really helpful, but I see Google is doing similar to this so the urls keeps changing.  I need to do the same in our site.  Please let me know is there any way or framework to achieve this.. thanks in advance..

Comment: @DilipRajkumar: Google isn't using Javascript to redirect the user.

Comment: Ohh ok..  Then how can I achieve this..  I am having lots of authenticated html pages, which has to redirect to login page if they are not authenticated.. Please help..

Comment: I can add this as a new question if you suggest

Comment: @DilipRajkumar: That depends entirely on what web platform you are using on the server. There should already be a bunch of questions here about doing a redirect whichever platform it is.

Comment: Thank you for the response, in my code all the back end is webservice..  So I will login using the ws and save the session id in cookie, then I will use that session id for rest of the API calls, what I need to do is, I people goes to authenticated pages with out login I have to redirect them to home page.. All my pages are html pages for better performance..  Please provide your advice..  Even I am new to this kind of architecture.. sorry for the lang reply..

Comment: @DilipRajkumar: If you are not doing the redirect when the user requests the page, then you simply can't do the redirect before the page starts to load.

Comment: ohh then It is good to control the auth in server side.. Please correct me if I am wrong.  Thank you for all your help..

Answer (score 0):

Script tags are execute as soon as they are encountered. Just put your script tag early, and then use a redirect if your condition is true. Hooking the window.onload event handler is how you get Javascript to trigger on load.

Comment: yes My script executed as soon as fast... but it loads a current page for 1sec then execute my script...

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to serve a page initially which contains merely the JavaScript which you need to execute within an HTML document? You can then request the page you want based on the result of the JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the jQuery [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method to load a part of a page conditionally, which is not running script before the DOM is ready, but may achieve what you want to do.